# Searching for multiple elements using std::find()

Tags: c++, vector, find, std

Is it possible to use `std::find()` to search for multiple elements with 1 call? Example: `std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0&&1&&D)`

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `std::find`.  Assuming `0&&1&&D` is meant to be a list of three values and you're trying to find an element in the vector with any of those values, you can use:

- [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a predicate (a lambda may be easiest e.g. `[](const T& x) { return x == 0 || x == 1 || x == d; }`, where `T` is whatever type your `vector` holds), or
- [`std::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) (the linked page has a good example).

Comment: Not exactly, but close. What im trying to do is find if my vector contains all those of those elements, i.e. `vector[0] == 1`, `vector[1] == 0`, `vector[2]= = D`. Does not have to be in those exact positions, but assuming a vector with size i. Likewise, they dont have to be adjacent.

Comment: Then you might as well put the 1, 0, D values into a second vector, and have a `for` loop over it calling `find` in the first vector for each of those values in turn.  It might be less cache friendly if the second vector is much smaller than the first, but I've no reason to think you've enough data in a performance-critical part of your program to make that a practical concern.  If you're determined to avoid that, you could use `find_first_of`, and each time a match is found remove the matching element from the set of values you're seeking, until it's empty (success) or you hit `end`.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) might work for you.

```
std::for_each(vector.begin(),
              vector.end(),
              [](auto& item) -> void {if (item == <xxx> ) { /* Use the item */ });
```

You asked in a comment:

> This may be a separate question, but is there a method i can use to search in a vector if certain elements are present?

[`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) is the function for that.

```
bool found = std::any_of(vector.begin(),
                         vector.end(),
                         [](auto& item) -> bool { return item == <xxx>; });
```

Comment: Could you explain the third parameter? what does `[](auto item) -> bool {return item == <xxx>l})` do?

Comment: That's a lambda function. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda for further details.

Answer (score 2):

The [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) states it pretty clearly:

> "**An iterator to the first element** in the range that compares equal to `val`.
>   If no elements match, the function returns `last`."

So you can't do it with just one function call.

Comment: This may be a seperate question, but is there a method i can use to search in a vector if certain elements are present? Or do i have to do it recursively?

Comment: Might want to check _Tony D_'s answer for that :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the three values to be adjacent, implementing `find()` yourself might be the easiest and simplest option:

```cpp
template <class Iterator, class T>
Iterator find_by_three_values(Iterator first, Iterator last, T value1, T value2, T value3)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value1
            && first + 1 != last && *(first + 1) == value2
            && first + 2 != last && *(first + 2) == value3) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its not possible with 1 call, though you can change the range of `std::find` with more efficient looping like following,

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(6);
v.push_back(10);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(20);
v.push_back(2);
int start = 0;
for(int m = start;m<v.size();m++){
    vector<int>::iterator i = find(v.begin()+start,v.end(),2);
    if(i != v.end()){
        cout<<i - v.begin()<<endl;
        start = i- v.begin() +1;
    }
}
```